# What does this Define mean?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm taking a course in **C** and came across this #define. Reading up on it, it is that you define something. Example:

```
#define FAMILY 4
```

Then every time I set something equal to family or call family it is the value 4.
But I also came across this:

```
#define EVER ;;
#define FAMILY 4
```

What does it mean if after ever there are two semicolons? Does it mean EVER = ";;"?

Comment: you are defining macro named constants, every where in your code  `FAMILY` will be replaced by `4` by pre-processor before compilation. EVER probably a macro constant to write within for loop in C `for(EVER)` = `for(;;)` = `while(1)` = infinite loop

Comment: Is `for(EVER)` actually more readable than `for(;;)`. An example in the K&R book suggested `#define FOREVER for(;;)` for an example which would almost make sense if you wanted it to be easy to grep for but if you have to type `for(EVER)` you may as well type `for(;;)` or `while(true)` or whatever you prefer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EVER will be equivalent to exactly this:

```
;;
```

This means that you could have:

```
#define EVER ;;

//..... 

for(EVER){printf("This will print forever");}
```

which will be equivalent to:

```
for(;;){printf("This will print forever");}
```

You should however exercise caution when using aliases for such structures, as your application gets bigger you could get weird and hard to debug issues if you mess some #define statement.

In my opinion, a classic `while(true)` might be healthier in the long run, though not as witty.

Comment: `#define HELL_UNFROZEN 1` --> `while (HELL_UNFROZEN) { ... }` (SCNR)

Comment: @glglgl or #define PIGS_DO_NOT_FLY true

Answer (score 5):

The preprocessor is a step that runs before the actual compiler runs. The preprocessor does a simple search-replace of macros in the source, and passes it on to the compiler proper.

For example, with the `EVER` macro as defined in your question, you could use it as

```
for (EVER) { ... }
```

and the preprocessor will simply transform it into

```
for (;;) { ... }
```

which the compiler will see.

Comment: The first two statements in this answer are not technically true. The preprocessor may be integrated into the compiler, and preprocessing may be intertwined with the rest of compilation, as it is in GCC, not performed before the rest of compilation. And macro substitution is not a simple search-replace; it operates on preprocessor tokens, not text, and has semantics beyond simple search-replace.

Answer (score 5):

It is a funny way to replace an endless loop

```
for(;;) { ... }
```

with

```
for(EVER) { ... }
```

in order to make clear it is an endless loop.

Another option would be to do

```
#define forever while (1)
```

so we can do

```
forever { ... }
```

or even

```
do { ... } forever
```